# Confused with meaning of the CostFinalize action

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want my custom action to be performed **after** a user viewed and modified features, which are to be installed, but **before** execute installing.

I tried to call my action before PublishProduct (it seems to me that it's the right point), but I got a linkage errors from WiX.

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action="ModifyConfigBeforeStartService" Before="PublishProduct"/>
</InstallUISequence>
```

The error is:

```
error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixAction:InstallUISequence/PublishProduct' in section 'Product:*'
```

Then I tried to call my action after CostFinalize.
From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368048(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The CostFinalize action queries the Condition table to determine which features are scheduled to be installed.

But (from the same doc):

> The CostFinalize action must be executed before starting any user interface sequence which allows the user to view or modify Feature table selections

How installer detects which features are to be installed, if user interface wasn't displayed yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PublishProduct exists in the execute sequence not the UI sequence.  The name of your custom action implies it should be scheduled before StartServices (also in the execute sequence) not the PublishProduct action.

File costing is another important concept for you to learn but not really relevant here.  I'd start with this required reading:

[InstallSite: Installation Phases and In-Script Execution](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and for the link. Now the concept is much clearer for me. After reading I customized a standard Wix dialog set (injected my custom dialog, to receive data to be saved in config file) and than called my custom actions inside InstallExecuteSequence.

Comment: Make sure you consider silent installations.  In that scenario the UI sequence is skipped.

Comment: Is it correct to disable silent installation for product? Or to log some error from my custom action dll? Otherwise I would have to skip some steps (for example, not launch my service, as it would have uninitialized configuration).

Comment: For a home user application, perhaps.  For a business app?  No.  Silent installation is a vital feature for enterprises to distribute applications to hundreds, thousands of machines.

Comment: Thanks, I'll investigate it.<br/>Also I encountered with another issue. From the link you've provided:  > "deferred execution customs actions cannot directly access installer properties".<br/>My custom action requires some property to be set, and as the action changes a configuration file, I made such action 'deferred'. The result is error in custom action due to trying to access required property.

Comment: Take a look at immediate vs deferred custom actions and the concept of CustomActionData.  It's the brain and brawn pattern.  Immediate has access to properties ( data acquisition and businesss logic ) but doesn't have elevated perms.  It passes data to non-impersonating deferred custom actions running in the system context to do the work.  Now we start to get into the concept of "costing" and script generation vs script execution.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for the tip about CustomActionData. Now it works:)